# asp.net mvc3 can Global.asax accept controller-less and action-less parameters?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, global-asax

I would like to have a default parameter for the URL so that when the user sends an argument on its own, such as:

http://mysite.com/argument

that argument gets (invisibly) routed first to SomeController/SomeAction/ID=argument and then, if not found to a 404 or 301.

I'm hoping that global.asax RegisterRoutes would have this functionality. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On writing question: please avoid adding signature as you already have it in your user name. If you happen to have name you like more than your user name - consider fixing user name instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a route to do this, but it will interfere with the "generic" way MVC is set up:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ControllerlessRoute",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action = "SomeAction" }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Route "/argument" to your action and return either interesting view or 404/301/302 results depending on your need:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ControllerlessRoute",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action = "SomeAction" }
);

class SomeController{
  ActionResult SomeAction(id)
  {
     if (NotFound)
     {
        return Custom404View();
     }
     else if (NeedRedirect)
     {
        return new Custom301View{Url:RedrectUrl}; 
     }

     return View();
  }
}
```

Sample of custom 301 View can be found http://forums.asp.net/p/1337938/2700733.aspx.

```
public string Url { get; set; }
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
   context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;
   context.HttpContext.Response.RedirectLocation = Url;
   context.HttpContext.Response.End();
}
```